# Правильна ли такая конструкция предложения?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис

Правильно ли сопряжены множественное и единственное число в предложении:
"Оказание услуг, относящихся к иным видам деятельности, не являющимся основным видом деятельности"?

Если это ошибка (я полагаю, что да), то к какой категории она относится? Грамматическая, лексическая (речевая)?

Comment: Зачем так сложно формулировать простые вещи? Можно ведь выразиться так: оказание услуг, не относящихся к основному виду деятельности.

Comment: Согласна, но это требования специального законодательства...(бюджетные учреждения). Спасибо за ответ, но все еще жду уточнения в части "русского языка"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Виды деятельности, не являющиеся основным видом*(?!) — на мой взгляд, некорректно. Если написано, что много объектов (не) являются одним объектом, то это может означать лишь то, что они **в совокупности** (не) являются этим.  (Например: *Россияне и украинцы не являются одним народом*). Ошибка [речевая](https://4brain.ru/blog/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B/), а более конкретно — синтаксическая (нарушение правил сочетания слов), а она уже порождает смысловую (лексическую), но последняя вторична.

*Виды деятельности, не являющиеся основными* — корректно, но исчезла информация о том, что есть только один основной вид деятельности. Если важно это подчеркнуть, то фразу нужно перестраивать, например так: "виды деятельности, отличные от основного" или "виды деятельности, не совпадающие с основным".

Comment: Спасибо огромное за разъяснения! Совершенно точно усмотрели смысл (основной вид действительно один, но информация об этом содержится по тексту ранее.. не связана с данным предложением..). Я сама думала немного перефразировать.. Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: М_Г! только сейчас обратила внимание.. Вы употребляете слово "Россияне" в смысловом значении "граждане России" или "русские" (как народ, этнос)? И вообще такой пример неоднозначный (и сам по себе ТАКОЙ спорный)). Тут проще было бы (можно ли?) такой пример привести (аналогия): ГрушИ (у меня "иные виды") не являЮТСЯ яблокОМ (у меня "основной вид") ... Правильно: груши не являются яблоками...

Comment: Наталья, Вы правы, пример спорный. Но он показывает, как правильно употреблять ед. ч. А про груши — о том как неправильно.

Comment: Кстати, пример я не придумал, а нашел в Интернете. (https://censoru.net/25096-odin-narod-boris-akunin-razbil-mif-pro-edinstvo-ukraincev-i-rossiyan.html). Исходя из текста, можно предположить, что так сказал Акунин.